# VS2010 Reference application that called library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dependencies

I'm writing an application that references an in house library, and I need to make a method call from the library, back into the application. I cannot "Add A Reference" because this would end in circular dependencies. How, therefore, do I reference this method from the library?

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to do.  Can you expand?  The built library has a dependency on the application referencing it?  What does the method do?

Comment: just a query - How come a library which calls back the calling app is a library ??

Comment: I am a little confused by your explanation. Are you saying the in house library already references your application assembly? If not then where is the circular dependency coming from?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common scenario in .NET programming.  For example, a button control has no clue what code should run when a user clicks it.

Use a delegate or event.